# Paritioning and Bucketing in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

My hive table will have call record data. 
3 columns of the table are field1- CALL_DATE, field2-FROM_PHONE_NUM, field3- TO_PHONE

I would query something like 
1) i want to get all call records between particular dates.
2) I want to get all call records for a FROM_PHONE phone number between certain dates.
2) I want to get all call records for a TO_PHONE phone number between certain dates.

My table size is approximately 6TB.

Can i know How do i need to apply partitioning or bucketing for better performance of all of my queries?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is always to get data between certain dates  and do filtering on it, so do table **partition biased on date .**

How to create [Link](https://www.altiscale.com/blog/best-practices-for-dynamic-partitioning-in-hive/) for dynamic partition

You can have partition key date as  yyyymmdd .

(like -- 20170406 for today(6th april 2017 ))

Comment: How do i make my query faster if i want to fetch from-date related call records.

Comment: if i understood you correct "u want to fetch  call record for given date" then if data is partitioned by date as mentioned in answer hive do get data from repatriation and query will be fast ...